# How to fix this "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction"?

Tags: android

I encountered the error today in my ubuntu while creating kivy app

`[DEBUG]: [DEBUG]:        * What went wrong: [DEBUG]:        Execution failed for task ':compressDebugAssets'. [DEBUG]:        > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction [DEBUG]:           > Java heap space`

My assets size is 240mb, when I reduce it to 100 mb everything works fine

Also when I added this

android.gradle_build_env = JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4g

I encountered another error

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> Self-suppression not permitted